# Colorear tabla con efecto cebra por grupos según el valor, de cada elemento

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Hola amigos, tengo una table donde muestro los datos de mi array, y lo que deseo es colorear cada las filas por grupos(por el campo n_comp) y darle el efecto cebra**

*Es decir, mis dos primeras filas con la n_comp 00000001 deberían tener la clase 'bg-dark' la tercera ya no porque tiene otra serie distinta, la cuarta debería tener la clase 'bg-dark' y las dos ya no deberían llevar la clase*

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    array: [{n_seri:'001','n_comp':'00000001',producto:'agua'},
            {n_seri:'001','n_comp':'00000001',producto:'gaseosa'},
            {n_seri:'002','n_comp':'00000002',producto:'leche'},
            {n_seri:'001','n_comp':'00000003',producto:'agua'},
            {n_seri:'003','n_comp':'00000004',producto:'cafe'},
            {n_seri:'004','n_comp':'00000004',producto:'gaseosa'}]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Serie</th>
      <th scope="col">Comprobante</th>
      <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(a,index) in array" :class="a.n_comp != (Object.assign({}, array[index+1])).n_comp ? 'bg-dark' : ''">
      <th v-text="index + 1"></th>
      <td v-text="a.n_seri"></td>
      <td v-text="a.n_comp"></td>
      <td v-text="a.producto"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**he estado tratando de la siguiente manera pero no lo consigo, si me pudieran ayudar les agradecería mucho**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del ciclo va a ser muy complicado poder agrupar filas que repiten un valor, porque necesitas dos variables:

- Una para almacenar el último valor mostrado y saber si debe agrupar con el elemento actual
- Otra para la clase, cada que haya un cambio de valor, también debe haber cambio de clase

Puedes crear un objeto personalizado para esas variables y acceder con [this.$options.nombreDePropiedad](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) que vas a usar en un método para saber qué clase usar en cada elemento.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    array: [{n_seri:'001','n_comp':'00000001',producto:'agua'},
            {n_seri:'001','n_comp':'00000001',producto:'gaseosa'},
            {n_seri:'002','n_comp':'00000002',producto:'leche'},
            {n_seri:'001','n_comp':'00000003',producto:'agua'},
            {n_seri:'003','n_comp':'00000004',producto:'cafe'},
            {n_seri:'004','n_comp':'00000004',producto:'gaseosa'}]
  },
  // Definir propiedades no reactivas, solo para uso local
  // Tú decides el nombre que le das al objeto
  local: {
      lastValue: '',  // Almacenar el último valor de n_comp
      lastClass: '',  // almacenar última clase usada
  },
  methods: {
      // Crear función para saber qué clase aplicar
      getClass: function(value) {
          // Si el valor actual no es igual al último mostrado, cambiar clase
          if(value != this.$options.local.lastValue) {
              // Actualizar último valor mostrado
              this.$options.local.lastValue = value;
              // Cambiar entre 'bg-dark' y cadena vacía, actualizando última clase 
              this.$options.local.lastClass = (this.$options.local.lastClass == '') ? 'bg-dark' : '';
          }
          // Devolver clase correspondiente
          return this.$options.local.lastClass;
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Serie</th>
      <th scope="col">Comprobante</th>
      <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(a,index) in array" :class="getClass(a.n_comp)">
      <th v-text="index + 1"></th>
      <td v-text="a.n_seri"></td>
      <td v-text="a.n_comp"></td>
      <td v-text="a.producto"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: deseo aplicar el estilo a los grupos por n_comp, sin importar que n_seri tenga, con el efecto cebra, primer grupo con el estilo, el siguiente no, el siguiente con estilo

Comment: @FredyAlarconOrdoñez, actualicé la respuesta para agrupar por `n_comp`.

Comment: gracias, justos lo que necesitaba